# How to change GPT partition type on windows?

Tags: windows, uefi, gpt, diskpart

The GPT format introduce far more place to metadata.
To set a partition type in diskpart, one use :

```
DISKPART> create partition msr
```

or

```
DISKPART> create partition efi
```

or

```
DISKPART> create partition primary
```

But how to do change the type after partition creation like changing primary to efi ?

Comment: note it doesn’t have to be done with diskpart, other built‑in tools can be used.

Comment: Please could you stick to standard ANSI text and refrain from using Unicode "lowercase capitals" or similar. It makes it impossible to search for your questions as "normal" search terms (non Unicode) will not be matched in your questions. This makes it harder for future visitors to find your question and thus reduces the audience of people who might be able to help you.

Comment: Change the type to what exactly?  There is only one type of GPT partition.

Comment: @Ramhound : for example convert [unknown to efi](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26700053#26700053). A ɢᴘᴛ partition have types set has flags *(you can combine several types)* ; associated ᴏꜱ ; id ; and guid.

Comment: I don't believe diskpart has the capability.

Comment: @Ramhound : you can already do things like`gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001`with diskpart *(where will set GPT_ATTRIBUTE_PLATFORM_REQUIRED GPT_BASIC_DATA_ATTRIBUTE_NO_DRIVE_LETTER which will prevent all kind of methods for assigning a drive letter, making it more restrictive as hidden)*. However, the type isn’t stored in the 64 bits in partition type. I also already commented it doesn’t have to be done with diskpart.

Comment: Why do you want to do this, exactly? If you just want to read or change a partition's data, you don't need to change its type. Knowing what you're trying to accomplish may let us solve the problem rather than answer the question.

Comment: @BenN : because of [this reason](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26700053#26700053).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DiskPart can actually do this. Select the appropriate disk and partition, then use the `set id` command. For example, this changes the selected partition into an EFI partition:

```
set id=c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
```

Using a combination of [the `set id` TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753840.aspx) and `detail partition`, I discovered these common possible values:

- Recovery: `de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac`
- Normal: `ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7`
- EFI: `c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b`
- Reserved: `e3c9e316-0b5c-4db8-817d-f92df00215ae`

It's probably a good idea to consult the partition attributes for a partition of a certain type (look at a healthy computer) so the set flags make sense. As you discovered, `gpt attributes` sets flags; `detail partition` displays them.

#### Danger zone: setting the Reserved type

The TechNet documentation says that DiskPart won't let you make a partition into a Microsoft Reserved one. That claim is true, so you might want to use a different tool. If you *really* want to use DiskPart, you'll have to whack the Windows disk management infrastructure it so that it doesn't know what types are not allowed. **Danger!** I have not tested the following steps on a bootable disk; they're here for entertainment purposes only. Do them at your own risk, preferably on a throwaway computer or VM.

Break out a hex editor - I like XVI32 - and open a copy of `vdsbas.dll` (in System32). That's the module that serves most disk-related operations, and it's the one responsible for policing partition types. The GUID of the Microsoft Reserved type starts at byte 0x21CD8 for the version that comes with Windows 10 x64; you should search for the hex string `16 E3 C9 E3` (0xE3C9E316 in little-endian). Flipping a bit there will make the whacked copy not know you're setting a special type. You'll have to change the security settings on the original copy of `vdsbas.dll` before Windows will let you overwrite it. You'll also have to make sure the Virtual Disk service isn't running (stopping it in Services is fine), otherwise the file will be in use.

Note that such Reserved partitions must not be associated with a volume. I do not know whether DiskPart has a way to keep a partition that way.

There's probably a good reason Microsoft doesn't let you set this type, so make a back-up of anything important on the drive if you decide to go this route. If you direly need such a partition back, it's probably better to reinstall/repair Windows from official media.

Comment: Ok, I thought`set id`was referring to an unique identifier much like ɢᴜɪᴅ instead of a type.

Comment: The microsoft reserved partition need to to carry a name in more the specific id. If it don’t you won’t be able to upgrade the windows® version without re‑installing.

Comment: Note a full list of Microsoft-documented guids for GPT partitions is available here: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=PARTITION_%2A+AND+valuetype%3ASystem.Guid

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a bit of confusion, or at least imprecise use of terminology, in this question and its discussion. Thus, it may be useful to review the GPT data structures, which are described in [the Wikipedia article on GPT.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) (The EFI spec is more authoritative, and is freely available, but requires accepting license terms to download. See [here](http://www.uefi.org/specifications) to get it.) GPT type codes are actually GUID values -- see the [partition type GUIDs table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) in the Wikipedia article for a listing of well-known values. There are also GPT attributes and partition names; these are three entirely independent data structures (although many partitioning tools set partition names based on the type code). I know of no GPT partition type called "primary." I suspect that the reference to this type is a result of confusion with MBR partitions, which can be primary, extended, or logical; but these concepts are meaningless in GPT. Some tools continue to apply the term "primary" in reference to *all* GPT partitions, presumably because the tools were originally written for MBR disks, and so require a primary/extended/logical identification for all partitions.

Type codes, in both MBR and GPT, identify the intended use of the partition. Windows, OS X, and some other OSes use type codes as a sort of "filter" -- these OSes ignore partitions that aren't of certain types, so that you can set up (say) a Linux filesystem on a partition with a Linux-specific type code and Windows won't try to format it. There are also several Windows-specific type codes (see the Wikipedia table), and some that are cross-OS (like the code for the EFI System Partition, or ESP).

Attributes are less commonly used (type codes are mandatory), but they may modify the way the OS or firmware treats the partition. A "hidden" attribute, for instance, tells the OS to ignore the partition. This may or may not be honored, depending on the OS. Attributes can vary from one partition type to another.

Partition names exist mainly for human consumption, so that you can identify partitions. I haven't investigated it extensively, but I think that OS X is finicky about the name assigned to its `Recovery HD` partition; in my (brief) tests, it flaked out when this partition was renamed. I haven't encountered any other case of OSes or utilities caring about partition names, although they're often assigned to descriptions associated with the type code when partitions are created.

I'm not very familiar with Microsoft's `diskpart` tool, but as Ben N specifies in his answer, it it possible to use it to set type codes to arbitrary GUID values. Other tools can do this, too, or can set type codes in some other way. My own [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`),](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) for instance, uses four-digit (two-byte) hexadecimal values as "shortcuts" to known GUID values; or you can enter GPT values "raw." See the [`gdisk` Walkthrough](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html) section of the documentation for information on how to do this. The libparted library (which is used by several Linux tools) sets type codes based on the filesystem you say will be used on a partition; but you can change them to a limited extent by setting "flags," some of which correspond to type codes and some to attributes. This is a rather confusing blending of two independent underlying data structures.

Comment: The Microsoft windows® reserved partition need to to carry a name or it will won’t be possible to upgrade the windows® version without re‑installing. id and ɢᴜɪᴅs are 2 different independent things with 2 different values for each partition.

Comment: If you just want to see these values in `gdisk` without looking anywhere else: `gdisk /dev/sdX`. Select the *extra functionality (experts only)* menu (press `x`) and then press `i` to *show detailed information on a partition*. You need to do it one partition at a time (perhaps there is a better way?)

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin's `fdisk` can change the partition type. (I would guess that WSL will let you do this too, but I have neither tried nor checked.) Disk devices are typically named `/dev/sda` (first disk) through `/dev/sdz` (26th disk). Here is how I changed the partition types for my second external disk, `/dev/sdc`:

Start with a Cygwin administrator's shell. I'll interleave commands and output here. Output will be indented. I use the `#` symbol on a line to start a comment that you must not copy/enter:

```
fdisk /dev/sdc

    Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.33.1).
    Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
    Be careful before using the write command.

Command (m for help): p    # Print the partition table

    Disk /dev/sdc: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: gpt
    Disk identifier: 0EB10471-5858-9090-8081-828310111213
    
    Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
    /dev/sdc1       2048    546208    544161 265.7M Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sdc2     546816    594403     47588  23.2M Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sdc3     595968 315179233 314583266   150G Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sdc4  948752384 950774893   2022510 987.6M Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sdc5  950775808 976768063  25992256  12.4G Microsoft basic data

Command (m for help): t    # Set the partition type
Partition number (1-5, default 5): 1

    Partition type (type L to list all types): l
      1 EFI System                     C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      2 MBR partition scheme           024DEE41-33E7-11D3-9D69-0008C781F39F
      3 Intel Fast Flash               D3BFE2DE-3DAF-11DF-BA40-E3A556D89593
      …

Partition type (type L to list all types): 1

    Changed type of partition 'Microsoft basic data' to 'EFI System'.

Command (m for help): p

    Disk /dev/sdc: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: gpt
    Disk identifier: 0EB10471-5858-9090-8081-828310111213
    
    Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
    /dev/sdc1       2048    546208    544161 265.7M EFI System
    /dev/sdc2     546816    594403     47588  23.2M Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sdc3     595968 315179233 314583266   150G Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sdc4  948752384 950774893   2022510 987.6M Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sdc5  950775808 976768063  25992256  12.4G Microsoft basic data
```

Repeat the process for each partition in turn until you have changed them all to the appropriate values:

```
Command (m for help): p

    Disk /dev/sdc: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: gpt
    Disk identifier: 0EB10471-5858-9090-8081-828310111213
    
    Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
    /dev/sdc1       2048    546208    544161 265.7M EFI System
    /dev/sdc2     546816    594403     47588  23.2M Microsoft reserved
    /dev/sdc3     595968 315179233 314583266   150G Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sdc4  948752384 950774893   2022510 987.6M Windows recovery environment
    /dev/sdc5  950775808 976768063  25992256  12.4G Microsoft basic data
```

Finally, write the changes to the disk:

```
Command (m for help): w    # Write to disk (and quit)

    The partition table has been altered.
    Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
    Syncing disks.
```

Note that this will allow you to set Microsoft Reserved partition type. At least for the partition label.